# Query the sum of a column during an exact date C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm using this code to insert data into an Access Database file

```
 decimal quantity;
        if (!Decimal.TryParse(textBox9.Text, out quantity))
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid number");
        else
        {

            using  (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=|DataDirectory|\\crepeDB.accdb;"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string query = @"insert into Sales (Sdate,SQuantity) 
                     values (@date, @qta)";
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", OleDbType.Date).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@qta", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = quantity;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Now I want to get the total SQuantity for today, so I used this code, but it keeps giving me errors

```
 public void Calculate()
    {

            using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=|DataDirectory|\\crepeDB.accdb;"))
        { 
                conn.Open();
                string query = @"select SQuantity SUM(SQuantity) AS 'Total' From Sales where Sdate = '"+ dateTimePicker1.Value +"'";
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            textBox1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); 

        }

    }

    private void frmShiftEnd_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Calculate();
    }
```

Comment: What errors? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I believe you have to take SQuantity out of the query in the select. Should be select SUM(SQuantity) AS 'Total'...

Comment: You're trying to give the date as a string in the `Calculate()` method. Why not use a parameter for the date like you did in the insert? You already know that works.

Comment: I've used the code provided by NicoRiff, but it gives me an empty value, although the records exist in the database. Not sure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string query = @"select SUM(SQuantity) AS 'Total' From Sales where Sdate = @datetime";
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@datetime", OleDbType.Date).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
```

I removed de SQuantity and added the value as parameters. Do not use the values of your fields directly to your sql text. It may lead you to have security incidents.

Comment: Thanks mate for reply, well, that doesn't give me error now, but returns empty value, also I wonder, while viewing the access file, I noticed that the full date was inserted including time as "2/21/2017 2:58:34 AM", could that be the reason why it returns empty? because it search using time as well?

Comment: yeah it can be... if you only want to search by date, then remove the time on your search... that got to work

Comment: Thanks for replying, Nico, but how can I do that? how can I make it automatically insert only date without time and search only date? I'm trying to make automatically show the daily SQuantity when the user click on Shift End button